# By whom and why was Winterfell castle put on fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [S02E10 of Game of Thrones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valar_Morghulis), we see the 20 men from Greyjoy army knock out Theon Greyjoy, also stabbing Luwin. And then they leave the castle gagging Theon. The Stark's ally forces were on their way to take back Winterfell. So who put the castle on fire and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Late Season 3 spoilers:

> Winterfell was torched by Ramsay Snow, the bastard son of Roose Bolton. He made a secret deal with Theon's men that in return for them leaving Winterfell and giving up Theon he would let them leave in peace. So they knocked him out (after giving a rather stirring speech), handed him over to Ramsay and left. Afterwards, Ramsay sacked the castle and set it on fire, all as part of his father's plans to overthrow the Starks.

Comment: Oh! I didnt know there was a spoiler for this. I would rather not read it before i finish S03 then. Thanks anyway

Comment: @KharoBangdo - As a rule of thumb, to avoid spoilers, save questions until you've seen all episodes up to the latest release.

Comment: Another rule of thumb is that your answer should make sense without the spoiler content. It might be useful to add a short sentence along the lines of "None of the known players did it, and in fact it was not revealed until season 3 who put the castle on fire."

Comment: @atticae: I understand your logic, but to me even _that_ is a spoiler. So we now are on the lookout for someone totally new, because no one known on the show currently is guilty. Sorry, but that's a spoiler to me.

Answer (score 1):

*SPOILERS*

> It was not really the Greyjoys. It was the bastard of Roose Bolton, Ramsay and his lot. Ramsay later on chops off Theon's bits and names him Reek.